# Merging data from different graphql resolvers in vue.js client side for simple outputting

Tags: vuejs2, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, vue-apollo

I do query cars from an api with a single query but two resolvers (listing and listings)(hopefully resolver is the right name for it). One car I get by the id via listing and the other cars I get without filters by listings. The resolvers output the data i a little different structure on the server-side but I do get the same fields just at different „places“. I want to merge the structure in order to get a single array I can simply loop over in vue.js. For the apicalls I do use vue-apollo.

Couldn't find any information to merge data client-side inside graphqlqueries. All I found is about handling it serverside with resolvers but it's an api I do not own.

Is it possible with graphql or do I have to merge it inside my vuecomponent and if so what would be the best way to do so?

The output will be a grid of cars where I show the car of the week (requested by id) together with the newest cars of the regarding cardealer.

**Full screenshot including response**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDhPU.png

Stripped down example with just the id to show the problem:

```
query CarTeaser ($guid: String! $withVehicleDetails: Boolean!) {
    search {
        listing(guid: $guid){
            details{
                identifier{
                    id #for example: here I get the id under details->identifier 
                }
            }
        }
        listings( metadata: { size: 2 sort:{ field: Age order: Asc}}) {
            listings{
                id #here it's right under listings 
                details{
                    …
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you're right, it should be handled server-side, but if it's not your API the only solution is to manipulate the data on the client side, meaning in your component.

It's probably a lot simpler to leave the `listings` array untouched and to just merge the `listing` element with it, like this for instance:

```js
// assuming 'search' holds the entire data queried from the api
const fullListing = [
   // car of the week, data reformatted to have an identical structure as
   // the 'other' cars
   {
     id: search.listing.details.identifier.id,
     details: {
       vehicle: search.listing.details.vehicle,
     },
   }, 
   ...search.listings.listings, // the 'other' cars
]
```